# Zurb's Foundation: disable image resize

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 6 and have some images in two column groups.
When i resize the browser viewport from 1200px width to 1024px width the big image gets smaller, the width shrinks see pictures below.

Is there a way to permit that?

I would prefer a constant distance between the big image and the small image, to set a fix "B" value (second image) that is independent of the user's viewport.

[image]

[image]

See full webpage can be seen on https://fadendaten.herokuapp.com/t/categories/clothing

Answer (score 0):

Its because your class .product-teaser-column has fixed width. Change that and it will be responsive again.

```
.product-teaser-column {
   width: 470px;
}
```

Comment: when it's responsive the image in the column will be resizable. i don't want that.